# files in C:\Windows\assembly\temp

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Every now and then my `C:\Winddows\assembly\temp` directory gets populated with folders and `dll` files. Sometimes the `dll`s I have there seem to interfere with what I have in my `GAC`. I have no conclusive evidence for this, but sometimes it seems to help if I remove the files and folders in the temp directory (if possible - sometimes those files are locked by e.g. Visual Studio or some other process).

Can someone explain how the temp folder relates to the `GAC`? Am I doing something wrong, or why do files end up in the temp folder?

Edit Note: GAC refers to [Global Assembly Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) I *guess*...

Comment: are you using asp.net apps ?

Comment: @FelicePollano, yes. I'm building sharepoint applications.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you are using or developing application having the AppDomain using the ["Shadow Copying Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx)" active. This is true for web applications and sometimes for NUnit tests, but again is a flag on the AppDomain, so potentially each application can acti in this way.

Answer (score 0):

But as per the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Assemblies stored in the global assembly cache are not shadow copied.